# $http GET returns complete HTML source

Tags: c#, angularjs, webmethod

I am trying to use $http to send a get request to my server. I have a webmethod that looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true,
ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)]
public static IList<EmailContentModel> GetEmailContents(int emailTemplateID, int? pageIndex, int? pageSize)
{
    var clientManagementRepository = GetClientManagementRepository();
    var emailContents = clientManagementRepository.GetEmailContents(emailTemplateID, pageIndex, pageSize);
    return emailContents;
}
```

When I use POST method (and change the webmethod to UseHttpGet = false) the following returns the correct data.

```
function getEmailContentDetails(pageIndex) {
    return $http({
    method: "POST",
    url: "EmailContent.aspx/GetEmailContents",
    data: JSON.stringify({ emailTemplateID: emailTemplateID, pageIndex: pageIndex, pageSize: pageSize }),
    headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
    }).then(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

But when I use the GET method

```
function getEmailContentDetails(pageIndex) {
    return $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "EmailContent.aspx/GetEmailContents",
    params: { emailTemplateID: 3, pageIndex: 1, pageSize: 10 }
    headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
    }).then(onSuccess, onError);     
}
```

It falls over and returns the complete HTML source of the page to me instead of the correct data. I have looked with SQL profiler and the DB is not even being hit with a request when I use GET. When I use ajax, I can use GET and it works fine.

Comment: try remove headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8" }

Comment: @Steve Still no good Steve.

Comment: what HTML did you get? An error page or 404 page?

Comment: @Steve I return the request to the console (for debugging), it's the same page that I issue the request from.

Comment: because get request append with url return the full page source and post only sendonly parameter to server and return back the data to you according your request.

Comment: @PankajGupta When I use a jQuery ajax call instead (with GET method), the correct data is returned. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: When you do the GET, check your browser's network activity so you can check the actual URL that's getting called.  Then copy that URL into a new browser window, see if you get the same.

Comment: @StaffordWilliams I get a MIME error when I do this. It seems to be that the response header is text/html when it breaks and application/json when it succeeds. How can I specify that it should be application/json?

Comment: Is this a classic asp.net webservice?  If I remember correctly, setting HttpGet on the method is not enough, you need to allow HttpGet requests in the web.config.  That is of course if your jQuery request is really doing a POST or not...

Comment: @StaffordWilliams I'm looking at the successful jQuery call and it is a GET, but more importantly, the request header is posting a Content-Type (application/json) and an Accept header (application/json). I can't specify a Content-Type header using angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, angular does not send the 'Content-Type' if there is no data attribute on the call to $http. This is why I was getting HTML back. The solution was to add an empty data attribute.

```
function getEmailContentDetails(pageIndex) {
    return $http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "EmailContent.aspx/GetEmailContents",
    params: bbparams,
    data: '',  <--TAA DAA
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }
    }).then(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
//add a name for the route:

[Route("GetEmailContents")]
public static IEnumerable<EmailContentModel> GetEmailContents(int emailTemplateID, int? pageIndex, int? pageSize)
{
    var clientManagementRepository = GetClientManagementRepository();
    var emailContents = clientManagementRepository.GetEmailContents(emailTemplateID, pageIndex, pageSize);
    return emailContents;
}
```

In your request angulars:(Warning , you forgot to put '  ' around the names of the parameters)

```
function getEmailContentDetails(pageIndex) {
    return $http({
    url: "EmailContent.aspx/GetEmailContents",
    params: { 'emailTemplateID': 3, 'pageIndex': 1, 'pageSize': 10 }
    }).then(function(dataResult){
        //success
        // if you use then method you have put .data to catch the result.
        $scope.result = dataResult.data;
        console.dir(dataResult.data);
 }, function(error){
        //rejected promise
 });     
}
```

And if you really put the method get try this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public static IEnumerable<EmailContentModel> Get(int emailTemplateID, int? pageIndex, int? pageSize)
    {
        var clientManagementRepository = GetClientManagementRepository();
        var emailContents = clientManagementRepository.GetEmailContents(emailTemplateID, pageIndex, pageSize);
        return emailContents;
    }
```

in your angularjs:

```
// Simple Get request example (passing data) :
$http.get(
        '/someUrl',
        { 'emailTemplateID': 3,
          'pageIndex': 1,
          'pageSize': 10 
        }
    ).success(function(dataResult){
    //your code.
    });
```

it will surely fit your code since I do not know .
I hope this will be useful to you and let me know if it works or not.